# How to apply nestjs existing function transaction

Tags: transactions, nestjs

I am studying nestjs.

I have a case where I need to create a transaction and execute multiple functions.

```js
async function1(updateDto:UpdateDto){
    const queryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    try{
     await queryRunner.startTransaction();

     //My function
     await this.updateUser(updateDto);
     await this.updateUserAndPet(updateDto);

     await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
      return true;
    }catch (error) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
      return false;
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
}
```

In the code above, the code below `//My function` is not transactional?

In each function, `await this.xxRepository.update()` is executed.

If the transaction does not apply, how can I do?

Do I have to unpack each function to use the queryRunner?

Please let me know if there is another way.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the code above, the code below //My function is not transactional?

No. Because there is no connection between `queryRunner` and `Repository.update` in your case.

In order to "connect" them you have two options:

1. Use `EntityManager` created by `myDataSource.manager.transaction`:

```js
await dataSource.manager.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
    await transactionalEntityManager.save(user);
})
```

2. Use `queryRunner.entityManager`:

```js
await queryRunner.manager.save(user)
```

> If the transaction does not apply, how can I do?

I think the most straightforward way in you case is to pass `queryRunner.manager` as argument to your functions (`updateUser` and `updateUserAndPet`). And use it to perform update on entity (instead of `this.Repository.update`). So you still can reuse the logic inside your functions and preserve decomposition.
You don't have to "unpack" it, but it comes with cost of additional function parameter.

For transactions I usually use a special class which implements the ["Unit of Work"](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern:

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work.

**UnitOfWork.ts**

```js
import { Connection, EntityManager, QueryRunner } from "typeorm";

export interface WorkFunction<R> {
  (entityManager: EntityManager): Promise<R>;
}

class UnitOfWork {
  private readonly queryRunner: QueryRunner;

  private readonly entityManager: EntityManager;

  constructor(private connection: Connection) {
    this.queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
    this.entityManager = this.queryRunner.manager;
  }

  public async start(): Promise<void> {
    await this.queryRunner.connect();
    await this.queryRunner.startTransaction();
  }

  public async commit<R>(work: WorkFunction<R>): Promise<R> {
    try {
      const result = await work(this.entityManager);
      await this.queryRunner.commitTransaction();

      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      await this.queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();

      throw err;
    } finally {
      await this.queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
}

export default UnitOfWork;
```

**Usage of UnitOfWork**

```js
import { Connection, Repository } from "typeorm";

class UsersService {
  constructor( private connection: Connection) {}

  public async updateUserAndPet(user: UserEntity, pet: PetEntity): Promise<void> {
    const work: WorkFunction<void> = async entityManager => {
      await entityMagager.update(UserEntity, user.id, { pet_id: pet.id });
      await entityMagager.update(PetEntity, user.id, { status: "happy" });
    };

    const uow = new UnitOfWork(this.connection);

    await uow.start();
    await uow.commit(work);
  }
}
```

But it might not fit your case if you can not extract the logic from your both functions into a single place.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed reply! I'll change the code based on what you wrote.